# Unable to restore folders on Outlook 2003.

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm unable to restore my old folders in Outlook 2003, i closed a tree folder from a PST but when i want to re add it, the old folders doesn't show up.

I tried a scanpst.exe and didn't work.

After run the SCANPST.exe says there are 12 folders.

Repair Office 2003 installation and didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restore the system or try that pst in other version of outlook (2007, 2010, etc.)